# ASP.NET DropDownBox has "Text" for both Text and Value properties

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Okay, I feel like I am missing something really simple here.  I have an ASP.NET DropDownList control:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="rightColumnDropDownList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

In the code behind, I have (simplified, but still has the problem):

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    ListItemCollection options = new ListItemCollection();
    options.Add(new ListItem("name", "value"));

    this.rightColumnDropDownList.DataSource = options;
    this.rightColumnDropDownList.DataBind();
}
```

However, the resulting rendered HTML has options that contain the "name" for both the value and the text of the option element.

```
<option value="name">name</option>
```

What am I missing here?  I also tried this to no avail:

```
options.Add(new ListItem(){ Text= "name", Value = "value"});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
options.Add(new ListItem { Text= "name", Value = "value"});
```

and then try specifying [DataValueField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [DataTextField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield.aspx) properties:

```
leftColumnDropDownList.DataValueField = "Value";
leftColumnDropDownList.DataTextField = "Text";
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. I don't understand why that is not the default behaviour.

Comment: The list item you're adding is a red herring.  The only significance is the fact that when you're data-binding, you have to set the `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` fields, otherwise the drop down will not know which fields to use.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code:

```
dropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem("text", "value"));
```

Comment: how is that different from what I am doing?

Comment: It's less code to write, and does the same thing. Are there any negatives to this?

Comment: I like this solution the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this: 
`leftColumnDropDownList.Items.Add("name", "value");`

Also, your markup says the id is `rightColumnDropDownList` and the code is referencing `leftColumnDropDownList`, could just be a mistake when writing the question, though.

Comment: Yes, just copy paste from my code while I was trying to simplify for my question.